# Why AWS Elastic Beanstalk shows half the no. of instances as Healthy Host Count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, infrastructure

I am quite sure how many instances are running based on what I see in the "Health" section of the Environment.

[image: Health showing 6 instances running]

But on the Monitoring page - the Healthy Host Count is consistently half the number of instances.

[image: Monitoring showing half the host count]

All the instances are "Healthy" - They are all showing OK for status.
Why does one instance count as 1/2 a host?

When I just use one instance, it shows 0.5 as a Host Count.
Can someone please explain what am I not seeing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `HealthyHostCount` is reported based on ALB nodes. So your six instances are divided into two nodes, giving an average of 3. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#metric-statistics) explain that as well:

> The Minimum and Maximum statistics reflect the minimum and maximum **reported by the individual load balancer nodes**. For example, suppose there are 2 load balancer nodes. One node has HealthyHostCount with a Minimum of 2, a Maximum of 10, and an Average of 6, while the other node has HealthyHostCount with a Minimum of 1, a Maximum of 5, and an Average of 3. Therefore, the load balancer has a Minimum of 1, a Maximum of 10, and an Average of about 4.

Comment: This answers the question! Thank you for providing the link as well!